# Python file association not working in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, associations

I am running Windows 10. I have recently changed location to my python folder and interpreter.

Unfortunately, when i now run python scripts in command prompt, I always have to type "python" before the name of the script I want to run.

Running the script directly - for example: C:\Python 37\mypythonscript.py -generates absolutely no reaction from the command prompt. I simply get back directly to C:\Python37>

If I however run C:\Python 37\python mypythonscript.py, the script is properly executed.

I have changed all the file associations using "ftype" and "assoc" in the command prompt. When I start command prompt and type "python", the python compiler correctly starts.

My problem is that I always have to type "python" before the name of my script for the command prompt to recognize that it needs to execute python.

I would like to open command, change directory to the directory with my python scripts, and simply run the python scripts by running the name of the scripts (mypythonscript.py) without having to type "python" in front of it.

Could you please help me identify what is wrong? How can I once again run python scripts in the command prompt without having to type "python" in front of the script's name?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can find the person who recommended using `ftype` and `assoc` for this, please tell them to stop misinforming the world. Those commands are from NT 4.0; they're outdated and practically worthless now. They only modify the simple per-machine setting in "HKLM\Software\Classes". The shell has grown much more complicated since then.

Comment: Reset your file association using Python's installer, making sure to install the py launcher, and then use the shell's "open with" dialog for a .py file. Select the Python application with a rocket in its icon from the listed appications (*do not browse for python.exe*) and select the option to always use it open .py files.

Comment: @ErykSun you should convert this to an answer. And it would be nice to know what effect `assoc` and `ftype` have nowadays as well as more information about what the current way of doing this is. Without this information, it's hard to tell the other person to stop misinforming the world.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a python 3 Virtualenv in powershell the above problem can be very confusing. Typically "py .\yourscript.py" or "py .\yourscript" will work but ".\yourscript.py" or ".\yourscript" will fail and might return a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module>' " error.

This happens because your .py association is not correct as described by Eryk Sun in the above second remark. The "py launcher" he names is, in most cases, "C:\Windows\py.exe". I my case it was already installed and I just needed to adjust the .py extension as described by him. It can also be done via the "Choose default apps by file type" settings.

A useful help is to define "$env:PYLAUNCH_DEBUG=1" in your powershell. After that "py .\yourscript.py" will have extra output showing where your python executable is found.
If there is no extra output it means, as before, that you don't have ".py" associated with "py.exe". If you start a "cmd" and "ftype python.file" looks ok, you need to read Eryk Sun's first remark :-)